# Why does Javascript parseInt('0x4A') return the same as parseInt('0x4Avv')?

Tags: javascript

Why does Javascript **parseInt('0x4Avv')** return the same as **parseInt('0x4A')**
I was counting on **parseInt('0x4Avv')** to return **NaN**.

Is there anyway to make it behave as such?

Even weird strings 'work', e.g: **parseInt('0x4Av--9-0-90v')** yields the same result as **parseInt('0x4A')**

Observed in all browsers....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the MDN parseInt documentation

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

There isn't a built in way to make it behave otherwise, but you could conceivably write your own int parsing function using regex that could be more strict.

Answer (score 4):

The `parseInt()` function doesn't care about trailing garbage in the source string. The `parseFloat()` function shares that behavior.

If you want to convert a string to a number and do so in such a way as to ensure the string was "all number", you can use the `+` unary operator:

```
var num = +someString;
```

That gives you a JavaScript number, so if you want an integer you can instead use one of these:

```
var intval = ~~someString;
var intval = someString|0;
```

Feeding bad strings as in your examples to any of those techniques will leave you with `NaN`.

Comment: Note: the source string is a hex string `0x4A` and not just a trash string.

Comment: @limelights yes I recognize that; the point is that the parser built into the `parseInt()` function just stops parsing when it sees something that it doesn't expect.

Comment: So sorry, I meant no offence! Just wanted to clarify for OP.

Comment: @limelights no your  comment was fine and helpful. I know what you meant :)

Answer (score 3):

`parseInt` ignores everything after an invalid number.

Here's is a little example of it behavior.

```
parseInt("12ab") // radix asumed to 10 since there isn't specified.
// 1 -> valid number
// 2 -> valid number
// a -> not valid number, DROP everything after this including this..
//
// so it endup behaving like:
parseInt("12") // 12
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in previous answers, both `parseInt` and `parseFloat` will convert all inputs to a string and then attempt to parse all numerical values up to the first non-numerical value (see [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for further reading). However, if you are trying to cast a string to a number and desire that it return a `NaN` value if the entire string does not represent a number you can use the [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) global object to do so:

```
> Number('0x4Avv')
NaN
> Number('0x4A')
74
> Number('0x4Av--9-0-90v')
NaN
```