# Why does parseInt('1 year old') return 1 but parseInt('I am 1 year old') returns NaN?

Tags: javascript, parseint

The code ran in developer console is shown below. Why does `parseInt` return the number present in [0]th index of a string but not return the number present in any other index in the string?

```
parseInt('i am 1 year old')
// output NaN
parseInt('1 year old')
// output 1
```

What is the reason why it behaves like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Javascript parseInt('0x4A') return the same as parseInt('0x4Avv')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29781856/why-does-javascript-parseint0x4a-return-the-same-as-parseint0x4avv)

Comment: it is attempting to parse the string.  It sees the first character is a numeric and everything after is not, so it sees just 1.   when it tries to cast i, it sees that *i* is not a numeric.  you can see it with various input tests of `parseInt('5trees');` and `parseInt('16 candles');`

Comment: Because that's how it is defined to work, as stated clearly in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Answer (score 2):

The `parseInt` function reads the string to a point it keeps getting numbers. So, `10 is a number` returns `10` because the function stops at third character, which is a space. But in case of `i am 1 year old`, it stops at `i` because it is not a number and returns `NaN` instead.

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the
>   specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and
>   returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates
>   numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: The relevant excerpt of the docs is this: "An integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, NaN is returned." The answer is completely right though, don't know why someone would downvote it.

Comment: Well to be fair, I think the information about leading and trailing spaces is important. Also, I wasn't aware of the radix consideration. So I added this paragraph.